# Flask flaskext.mysql no attribute connection

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to establish a connection to an sql database, but I end up with

```
AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

I've read through the documentation, and it looks like this is the proper way to create a cursor:

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'sql3.freemysqlhosting.net'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'sql1234567'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'abcdefg'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'sql1234567'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '3306'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM users''')
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    return str(rv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Edit: using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWO_VpI5wn8 as a tutorial and the docs are http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing incorrect module here.

**Solution is**

Instead of importing

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

import this which is different module (Follow [this](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

This looks like an auto import issue from some IDE. As these two modules are different, you can install these two packages as following:

`pip install flask-mysqldb` and
`pip install flask-mysql`

**EDIT**

If you want to use the previous module, you will have to follow [this](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the cursor can be used as following:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
```