# How do you install MySQL for Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am using OS X Yosemite, Python 3.6.2 and basically went through every single stackoverflow post regarding installation of MySQL into flask.

I've tried pip install `flask-mysqlDB` which gives me the error

```
Collecting flask-mysqldb
  Using cached Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb)
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-32rvmlzy/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-32rvmlzy/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-32rvmlzy/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-32rvmlzy/mysqlclient/
```

none of the `sudo apt-get` commands work because of my Mac version. Installed homebrew by `brew install python` and I am still unable to use the `sudo apt-get` command.

My pip list is

```
click (6.7)
Flask (0.12.2)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.9.6)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
mysql-connector-python-rf (2.2.2)
mysqlclient (1.3.10)
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
Werkzeug (0.12.2)
```

Now I have an error saying:

```
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-n8on2g_t/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-n8on2g_t/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-n8on2g_t/MySQL-python/
```

Comment: If you can't use apt that is really a bigger problem you should resolve, and it's not related to Python.

Comment: There are two different packages as explained herehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521644/flask-flaskext-mysql-no-attribute-connection/45522011#45522011

Comment: @Nabin Thank you very much! I think I was able to install it as I got the message "Successfully installed flask-mysqldb-0.2.0" Ive got "Flask-MySQLdb (0.2.0)" in my pip list. MySQL is installed probably, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install MySQL package and dependencies

**Ubuntu**

```
 sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

**Mac OS**

```
 brew install mysql-connector-c
```

using **PIP**

```
 pip install MySQL-python
```

In Python 3, **ConfigParser** has been renamed to **configparser** . The package you are installing does not support Python 3.

so in Python 3

```
pip install configparser
```

in python 2

```
pip install ConfigParser
```

Comment: @Kaliz I still get the same error as I tried both pip install configparser and ConfigParser. Requirement already satisfied: configparser in /Users/yuyaKawahara/Desktop/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: @Robert install only one configparser or ConfigParser according to python your python version

Comment: I'm using python3 so I installed configparser but I still get the same error. Tried the other way around but the same result...

Comment: I see a couple of posts saying that just having mysqlclient will suffice, is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Root cause of your problem lies here

> OSError: mysql_config not found

mySQLdb is a python interface for mysql, but it is not mysql itself. You need to install mysql first.

See this link below.
[mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Comment: I installed MySQL but I am stIll getting an error and also I am still unable to use the sudo apt-get command.

Comment: I gusess you are installing wrong package which is not compatible with python version. My guess is you are using python3 where ConfigParser(in python2) has been renamed to configparser

Comment: When you say wrong package, what should I uninstall and install what package?

Comment: try to use the mysqlclient package which is a replacement of MySQL-python. It is a fork of MySQL-python with added support for Python 3. Use command: pip install mysqlclient

Comment: I've done that already and I get 
"Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages" am I able to use MySQL at this point? What command can I type to see if this package is working?

Comment: Then where are you getting that module not found error?

Comment: @Robert I update my answer check it this is due  to Python version

Comment: @flamelite 
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-ggizmz58/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/var/folders/c4/y49xcq6j6jlcr_8yyckm75th0000gp/T/pip-build-ggizmz58/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Comment: flask-mysqldb is using wrong package so first uninstall that MySQL-python package

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are confused about what you're installing.  You need two things: MySQL, and a Python module that lets Flask use MySQL.  You're installing the latter, but it does no good unless you actually have MySQL.  MySQL is software that is totally separate from Python, so anything pip-based won't succeed in installing it.  Stop searching for how to install MySQL "into Flask" and start googling things like "how to install MySQL on a Mac" and you'll be on the right track.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was able to install MySQL but now I get an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'